# What is the difference between (char)0 and '\0'? in C

Tags: c, null-character

What is the difference between using `(char)0` and `'\0'` to denote the terminating null character in a character array?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The backslash notation in a character literal allows you to specify the numeric value of a character instead of using the character itself. So `'\1'`[*] means "the character whose numeric value is 1", `'\2'` means "the character whose numeric value is 2", etc. Almost. Due to a quirk of C, character literals actually have type `int`, and indeed `int` is used to handle characters in other contexts too, such as the return value of `fgetc`. So `'\1'` means "the numeric value as an int, of the character whose numeric value is 1", and so on.

Since characters *are* numeric values in C, "the character whose numeric value is 1" actually *is* `(char)1`, and the extra decoration in `'\1'` has no effect on the compiler - `'\1'` has the same type and value as `1` in C. So the backslash notation is more needed in string literals than it is in character literals, for inserting non-printable characters that don't have their own escape code.

Personally, I prefer to write `0` when I mean 0, and let implicit conversions do their thing. Some people find that very difficult to understand. When working with those people, it's helpful to write `'\0'` when you mean a character with value 0, that is to say in cases where you expect your `0` is soon going to implicitly convert to `char` type. Similarly, it can help to write `NULL` when you mean a null pointer constant, `0.0` when you mean a double with value 0, and so on.

Whether it makes any difference to the compiler, and whether it needs a cast, depends on context. Since `'\0'` has exactly the same type and value as `0`, it needs to be cast to `char` in exactly the same circumstances. So `'\0'` and `(char)0` differ in type, for exactly equivalent expressions you can either consider `(char)'\0'` vs `(char)0`, or `'\0'` vs `0`. `NULL` has implementation-defined type -- sometimes it needs to be cast to a pointer type, since it may have integer type. `0.0` has type `double`, so is certainly different from `0`. Still, `float f = 1.0;` is identical to `float f = 1;` and `float f = 1.0f`, whereas `1.0 / i`, where `i` is an int, usually has a different value from `1 / i`.

So, any general rule whether to use `'\0'` or `0` is purely for the convenience of readers of your code - it's all the same to the compiler. Pick whichever you (and your colleagues) prefer the look of, or perhaps define a macro `ASCII_NUL`.

[*] or `'\01'` - since the backslash introduces an *octal* number, not decimal, it's sometimes wise to make this a bit more obvious by ensuring it starts with a 0. Makes no difference for 0, 1, 2 of course. I say "sometimes", because backslash can only be followed by 3 octal digits, so you can't write `\0101` instead of `\101`, to remind the reader that it's an octal value. It's all quite awkward, and leads to even more decoration: `\x41` for a capital A, and you could therefore write `'\x0'` for 0 if you want.

Answer (score 31):

They're both a 0, but `(char) 0` is a char, while `'\0'` is (unintuitively) an `int`.  This type difference should not usually affect your program if the value is 0.

I prefer `'\0'`, since that is the constant intended for that.

Comment: I agreen - when you resort to casting I think that you should have at least another think about the problem. Why compare an Apple with an Orange?

Comment: He shouldn't have to cast.  I believe `char c = 0;` is legal, and it compiles on gcc with `-Wextra -pedantic`.  I just think `'\0'` better expresses the intention.

Comment: I have truncating a string as part of my code. So while adding null character at the part where I have to end it I got a confusion as to which representation is better.

Answer (score 2):

Zero can mean a lot of different things in C. You should use the null character '\0', because then there can be no confusion over that your intention is string termination.

If you set a char to 0, that can mean null termination, but it can also mean that you are just using the char as an 8-bit integer for calculations, rather than as part of a string.
This can be confused further if you are also using pointers in the same code and compare them against zero, which is then a null pointer.

Comment: Oops, I've downvoted this by accident (finger fumble). Too late to fix it, but if you make an edit I could remove the downvote.

Answer (score 1):

Character array means You are taking String so I advise you to use `'\0'` at the end of character Array after reading all the Characters of from user because `0` is simple Character but `'\0'` is `NULL` which indicates end of String.

Comment: `(char) 0` and `'\0'` is the same value, but `'\0'` is most used, because this is the `char` intended for null character.

Comment: @chema989 `(char) 0` and `\0` are different values in C because they have different types.